# django slow POST response

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to learn python and django by creating a server on an raspberry pi 3  to accept data from some IoT projects around the house.

I have set up the server and successfully managed to POST data to a url. However, I'm seeing that that the POST request takes about 1s. This is far too slow if I want several IoT devices feeding data back to the pi.

```
@csrf_exempt
def update(request):

  if request.method == "POST":
    key = request.POST.get("key", "")

    if key == settings.API_KEY:
        deviceID = request.POST.get("id", "")
        format = request.POST.get("format", "")
        datatype = request.POST.get("datatype", "")
        data = request.POST.get("data", "")

        fields = [format,datatype,data]

        WriteFields(deviceID,fields)
        return JsonResponse({"result": "received"})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "invalid_key"})

return JsonResponse({"error": "no_post"})
```

I ran a quick script to test the POST rate

```
import requests

for i in range(100):
    r = requests.post("http://heimdall:8000/sensors/update/", data={'key': 'testkey', 'id': '123456', 'format': 'temp', 'datatype': 'c', 'data': '12'})
    print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

The timestamps in the django terminal were showing the response about every 1s. To eliminate the pi being the bottle-neck I ran the same django project on my i3 based Plex media server and I get similar results.
I've also tested sending POST requests using CURL from windows cmd line and see the same response time. Is this a fundamental limit of POST? Or is the problem likely to be in my project somewhere?

**UPDATE**
I've removed most of the code from the Update function and re-run

```
@csrf_exempt
def update(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        key = request.POST.get("key", "")
    return JsonResponse({"test": "test"})
```

but the response rate is still around 1s.
I've also noted the comments about using `aiohttp`, I will investigate this next.
I've tried setting `DEBUG = False` in settings.py with no change.

**UPDATE2**
Interestingly actually running the request on my nodemcu esp8266 IoT device I don't see this delay... the serial output from the Arduino console DOESN'T pause for 1s and it still successfully reads the response from the server.

Comment: We need to know what your `WriteFields()` function looks like

Comment: not specifically related to your question but you cannot test an API like that. the test client requests must be made asynchronously. your requests are being queued with your current method. use `aiohttp` to perfom async requests.

Comment: It seems that your WriteFields() function would use several IO operating which will consume a long time.

Comment: As @wpercy mentions, it's probably the `WriteFields()` function. Comment it out and re-run your tests?

Comment: If you are running a dev server, it runs on a single thread. It's not designed for heavy hitting. You are hitting the link 100 times.